# searching for words starting with specific letters using JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript

**I need to find all the words in a string array which start with m but not have m in the middle?**

```
var arr = "Hello my mother! how is Ramy?";
```

I tried that:

```
var ragexp = new RegExp("\sm[a-z]*|^m[a-z]*", "g");
var test = regexp.test(arr);  // test should be true if anything matched
```

Comment: You can try something like \wm[^m]+

Comment: `"Hello my mother! how is Ramy?".match(/\bm[a-ln-z]*\b/gi);`

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will be useful for you:

```
\bm[^m]*?\b
```

[image]

I recommend this page for see more visual the expressions, just select the Flags(global, case insensitive):
[enter link description here](https://regexr.com/)